# Can we Hibernate a Virtual PC, and then take that image and use it for "Super Fast Boot up (Wake up)"?

Tags: windows-xp, virtualbox, virtual-machine, microsoft-virtual-pc, hibernate

Since if we hibernate a PC, and "wake it up", it will be a super fast process (compared to Booting up XP from start, for example), so, can we Hibernate a Virtual PC, and then keep that image.vhd and then use it to "wake up" to XP?

However, Virtual PC 2007 and the MS IE 8 on XP SP3 image doesn't seem to have an option to Hibernate a PC.  Anybody familiar with Virtual PC know how this can be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you close out VPC and choose "Save State" it is the same as hibernating.

Comment: +1 Save State will be faster than Hibernate because, in Save state Virtual PC will save the state, whereas in hibernate Windows will dump the image which will increase the image size + Virtual C will also have to do stuff during initialization.

Comment: If you save state, there seems to be a new .vsv file... about 98MB... I want to "take a snapshot" and be able to "boot up" to this snapshot in the future all the time. So if I save state, I need to use 2 images? (the .vhd and the .vsv?)